# Pass sub function

Tags: r

I am using the function below which summarise data only if column exists.

```
dummy <- function(df, arrear_var=NULL, pos_var=NULL) {

  if (!missing(arrear_var)) {
    arrear_var <- sym(arrear_var)
  }

  if (!missing(pos_var)) {
    pos_var <- sym(pos_var)
  }

df %>% summarise(lt = if(exists(as_label(enquo(arrear_var)), where = .)) sum(as.numeric(as.character(!!arrear_var)), na.rm = T) else NA,
                 pt = if(exists(as_label(enquo(pos_var)), where = .)) mean(as.numeric(as.character(!!pos_var)), na.rm = T) else NA)
}

dummy(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
```

Can I create separate function for this part of code and pass it in above function -

```
exists(as_label(enquo(var)), where = .)
```

Comment: It is used if a variable is factor.

Comment: In that case, you can wrap with `type.convert`.  Please check my solution below

Comment: I have updated my function. Can `summarise_at` work only if column exist (like I have used in my function)?

Comment: Thanks a ton. Can it be modified to summarise by group?

Comment: I apologise for not being clear at start. The reason I rely on exists() - It's robust to all these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to wrap the function with `possibly` to return `NA` if it fails

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
fn1 <- possibly(function(data, varName, func) {
     func(data[[varName]], na.rm = TRUE)


       }, otherwise = NA_real_)





dummy <- function(df, arrear_var, pos_var) {
        tibble(lt = fn1(df, arrear_var, sum), pt = fn1(df, pos_var, mean))


}

dummy(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#     lt    pt
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  876.  3.76

dummy(iris)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#    lt    pt
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1    NA    NA

dummy(iris, "Sepal.Length")
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#     lt    pt
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  876.    NA
```

---

If we want to do a grouping without changing the 'fn1', an option is `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
dummy <- function(df, arrear_var, pos_var) {
    df %>% 
       group_split(Species) %>%
       map_dfr(~ tibble(Species = first(.x$Species), 
          lt = fn1(.x, arrear_var, sum), pt = fn1(.x, pos_var, mean)))


   }




dummy(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species       lt    pt
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 setosa      250.  1.46
#2 versicolor  297.  4.26
#3 virginica   329.  5.55


dummy(iris, "Sepal.Length")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species       lt    pt
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 setosa      250.    NA
#2 versicolor  297.    NA
#3 virginica   329.    NA

dummy(iris)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species       lt    pt
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 setosa        NA    NA
#2 versicolor    NA    NA
#3 virginica     NA    NA
```

Comment: But I have many statements within summarise function so I have to write if(missing(arrear_var)) { for each of the variable

Comment: @john Are these statements based on the same variable or do you have mutiple arguments to function

Comment: No, different variables

Comment: @john But, your function showed only two arguments - 1) data, 2) variable name

Comment: My bad. In my original function, I have many arguments - function(df, arrear_var, pos_var, gf_var). I simplified my function for example.

Comment: Thanks. For my third argument, I need mean( ).